# What is the template name for www.mysite.com/user/login

Tags: theming

I have literally tried every combination possible, what am I missing?

page--user--login.tpl.php
page--user.tpl.php
page--login.tpl.php
user--login.tpl.php
page-user-login.tpl.php

Comment: Which version of drupal you are working on 7 or 6?

Answer (score 1):

page--user--login.tpl.php   ... if you create one, make sure you flush your cache!

Also, check out this module: 
https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer

It'll help you determine these sorts of things, just don't leave it running after you're done development!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [template suggestion](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) following will be the template file for `user/login` page:

> page--user--login.tpl.php

However to use tme above template you may require the following template:

> page--user.tpl.php

Also make sure you **CLEAR THE CACHE** after applying the changes.

Reference:
https://drupal.org/node/1195754

---

Alternatively if you want to define the custom suggestion for the `user/login` page than you can do it with the `phptemplate_preprocess_page` as following:

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  // Check to see that the user is not logged in and its correct page.
  if ($vars['user']->uid == 0 && arg(0) == 'user' && (arg(1) == '' || arg(1) == 'login')) {
    // Add suggestion for template-file "page--login.tpl.php" for user login page
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__login';
  }
}
```

Now you can use  **page--login.tpl.php** for the `user/login` page.